# How to force Mozilla Firefox 19.0.2 to use DX11 API in HW Acceleration?

Tags: firefox, directx-11, hardware-acceleration

I would like to know if there's a way to force Mozilla Firefox to use DX11 API in hardware acceleration? I've searched about:config and I found nothing.
To prevent questions, IE10 loads DX11 dlls but it uses it for different purposes, maybe for rendering GUI, not the hardware acceleration.

Thanks in advance.